# jQuery doesn't run in Safari on form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, safari, submit

I have a peculiar issue which is giving me headaches... The following code works perfectly in Firefox but not in Safari on Mac OS.

I want to display a simple "Loading message" while files are being uploaded. So my page looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#upload').on('submit', function () {

                    $("#loading").fadeIn();

                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="loading" style="display:none">UPLOADING...</p>


            <form name="upload" id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type='file' name='file[]' multiple/>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload..."/>
            </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

On Firefox, the "UPLOADING..." line shows up while the files are uploading before transfering me to upload.php. On Safari, the "UPLOADING..." line *doesn't show* and it transfers me to upload.php once the files are uploaded.

If this is something not supported in Safari, how can I achieve exactly the same feature?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: is the binding syntax correct? so far I know it would be like `$(document).on('submit', '#upload', function(){})`

Comment: I've just noticed the exact same behaviour... sounds more like a bug with safari if you ask me.

Comment: Encountered this just now too, sounds like a problem with Safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got it working...

Instead of a 'submit' button, I changed it by a 'button' with id='send'. I modified the script to first show the p tag on click and then added the form submit in the callback like so:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#send").click(function () {

                    $("#loading").fadeIn(function () {
                        $("#upload").submit();
                    });

                });

            });
</script>
```

And it works in all browsers now. Tested in IE, FF, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: this is not the recommended way! but that's up to you :)

Comment: Errr... fine but would you care to share the recommended way, then?

Comment: that's your initial implementation. but just wondering about safari issue.