# Safari ignores submit alterations in onclick event

Tags: javascript, safari, submit

For a Drupal site I've developed a rather simple module to prevent users of pressing multiple times on a submit button. When the submit button is pressed it's replaced with a small message to have some patience.

The problem in all browsers it seems to work fine with the exception of Safari.

```
    $("input[id^='edit-submit']").click(function(e){
        var message = Drupal.t('Please wait...');
        $(this).hide();
        $('<span>' + message + '</span>').insertAfter(this);
    });
```

When I look into the debugger I see an attribute appearing style="display: none;" but Safari seems to ignore it. When I manually (through the developer tools) add a display:none the button disappears.

I don't know it  [jQuery doesn't run in Safari on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673568/jquery-doesnt-run-in-safari-on-form-submit) is related because when I add a console.log() between the click function body it is executed once (the $(this) value also points to the correct element) but it doesn't respond to any changes on that button.

It seems that from the moment you click on the submit button it is in some kind of locked state - which would also prevent double submits - but I want to be rather sure this is standard behaviour for safari then a bug that could haunt me in the future.

I've tried googling on certain keywords but I couldn't find anything documentation that describes this behaviour in Safari.

EDIT: I also tried removing (and detaching) the button on the onclick which makes the button disappear, but then the form doesn't get submitted anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
.css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work. It is also roughly the same as hide() "The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ) , except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache " -> http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Try .detach() then, to temporary remove element from DOM.

Comment: Thx for thinking alone - but from the moment that I detach() (same with remove) the submit button, the form doesn't get submitted anymore. I'm gonna edit my original question to add this piece of information.

Comment: Same behaviour hide() seems to work but it halts submitting the form. The same for detach and remove.