# jquery show() or fadeIn() not working with Submit Form on Safari Mac

Tags: jquery, safari, submit, show, fadein

The HTML snippets:

```
<div id="loadingDiv"><img src="images/loader.gif" id="loadingImage"></div>
```

also:

```
<input id="form1Submit" type="button" class="button" name="Submit" value="Search"/>
```

The CSS:

```css
#loadingDiv
{
    position:absolute;top:200px;
    z-index:101;
    display:none;
}
```

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form1Submit").click(function(){
        $("#loadingDiv").show();
        $( "#form1" ).submit();
    })
```

The intention is to display a "loading" graphic in the foreground when a search form is submitted. I started out with a regular "submit" button, but changed it to a generic button and placed the submit function on it with a script.

This has worked in every incarnation, on every browser, except for Safari on Mac. On a Mac, the search runs without the foreground graphic, and we move on to the results. If I hit the BACK button, the graphic is THEN visible, as if it displayed, but the page URL was moving on before it was completed. I thought putting the the submit function into the jquery would solve this, but it did not. I also tried .fadeIn() instead of .show().

There is a very similar thread that I cannot respond to, and it offers a fix that I have already tried, unsuccessfully, here: [jQuery doesn't run in Safari on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673568/jquery-doesnt-run-in-safari-on-form-submit)

I would love any ideas. I am baffled.

Comment: Ugh, please use proper markup. Paste your actual code and use the `{}` tool to mark it as literal code, don't paste it as HTML entities.

Comment: Changes to the DOM don't become visible until the script returns to the main event loop. Since your script is submitting the form, it doesn't go to the event loop until the new page is loaded.

Comment: So sorry!  First time submitting a new question.   This should be readable now.

Comment: The script curently is making the change before the submission, so it seems like it should display before the load begins.  Is there a suggestion on how I might make this work on this platform?

Comment: Yes, it makes the change before the submission, but it never returns to the main event loop.

Answer (score 1):

This worked, and it is only slightly different than the 'hack' that you submitted to me, Barmar:

```
   $("#form1Submit").click(function(){
   $("#loadingDiv").fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function(){   
    $( "#form1" ).submit(); 
},500);
```

})

After doing more reading, I kept finding the same complaints about how Safari/Mac handles the DOM when a new location is called.  I am not certain why your code did not work for me.  I do not have enough casual access to a Mac at the moment to fully explore this.

Comment: I was having this issue in iOS chrome and safari, the timeout solution solved this. This seemed to be a race condition problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack, but you could try:

```
$("form1submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#loadingDiv").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#form1").submit();
    }, 10);
});
```

If you use `fadeIn`, you can do the submission in the callback function:

```
$("form1submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#loadingDiv").fadeIn(function() {
        $("#form1").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tested both of these.  Initially, each broke the page.  The first one improved when I eliminated the e.preventDefault() function, and changed the function within the timeout to plain javascript, as opposed to jquery . . . but it still did not fix the original problem.   I was unable to make the second solution work without breaking the page.  

I really thought those looked like great solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and came across this question and figured out how to fix your problem, as well as mine.
I used the fadeIn method and did the following code below and it worked for me:

```
$("form1submit").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#loadingDiv").fadeIn();
});
```